# How to add all possible attributes (including other directives) in my directive?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a directive like so:

myTemplate.html:

```
<div class="myWidget">
    <input type="text" class="someClass blah blah" ng-model="myModel" ng-change="myChange" />
</div>
```

myDirective:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp.myWidgets.someWidget')
        .directive('someWidget', someWidget);

    someWidget.$inject = ['$timeout'];

    function someWidget($timeout) {

        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
            link: link,
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                myModel: '=ngModel',
                myChange: '&ngChange',
                // ADD ALL OTHER POSSIBLE ATTRIBUTES HERE. BUT I DONT THINK THAT'S PRACTICAL.
            }
        };

        function link(scope, elm, attr) {
        }
    }
})();
```

Usage:

```
<some-widget ng-model="someModel" .... > </some-widget>
```

Now what if I want to add other stuff like ng-show? ng-hide? ng-change? I dont think it's practical to add all of them one by one. Is there any way to add them without specifying them on the scope one by one? This directive will be used by so many pages so I can't predict what other attributes or directives other will people will add.

Thank you.

Comment: You've got an isolated scope in your directive, you don't have many other options than to map them in the scope object.

Comment: what if I remove the scope? Is it possible to just like loop through each attr and add them as elements to myTemplate and keep the binding?

Comment: If you remove the scope property in the directive then it inherits the scope from the controller directly. This means that you can't use the directive more than once in that controller.